# Cut Dendrogram with Matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

is there any way to cut a dendrogram in Matlab ?

I would like to have a limit at a distance of 100, but I can't figure out how to add it into the function.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a simple figure with axes. You can control the visible y-range with the function `ylim()`. In your case it's `ylim([0, 100])`.